# Click button but multiple classes

Tags: python, selenium

I can click the "**AKZEPTIEREN**" button using XPATH like this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/button[2]'))).click()
```

To make it more dynamic I want to use a class, so this would be:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'primary.accept.no-pop-execute'))).click()
```

But the class "primary accept no-pop-execute" is twice on the site. So what can I do to choose the first one?

Page: https://fremdgehen69.com

Button: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code using xpath expression that will select a single element and click on it because `click()` method  requires a single selection:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="primary accept no-pop-execute" and contains(., "Akzeptieren")]'))).click()
```

Comment: What does the . mean after contains(  ? =)

Comment: dot(.) Means to select text node value which is here Akzeptieren